# How are these X and Y variables used in Linear regression?

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, linear-regression

I am trying to predict the cost of a certain item using simple linear regression. As input data I Use the cost of the item.

The code seems to work, but i somehow cannot comprehend how the X and Y are used when applying linear regression. I use X as the item cost and Y as the label (creating a new row with shifted data of X)

```py
df = df[['Item Price']]
forecast_col = 'Item Price'
forecast_out = int(math.ceil(0.0000005 * len(df)))
df['label'] = df[forecast_col].shift(-forecast_out)

X = df[['Item Price']]
X = preprocessing.scale(X)
X_lately = X[forecast_out:]
X = X[:-forecast_out]

df.dropna(inplace=True)

y = np.array(df['label'])

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=0)
clf = LinearRegression(n_jobs=-1)
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)

forecast_set = clf.predict(X)
```

How are the X and Y variables used in solving the linear regression equation of Y = a + bX

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your line :

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=0)
```

splits each of your X and y into two samples each : a train with 80% of the data and a test with the other 20%. Then the line :

```
clf = LinearRegression(n_jobs=-1)
```

creates a Linear Model. And with your last line :

```
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

the linear model uses all the (x,y) in X_train and Y_train to compute the best linear regressor.

---

In a more mathematical approach, the algorithm uses all the (x, y) contained in your X_train and Y_train to find a and b that minimises the equation E :

E = SUM(y_i - a*x_i - b)

The a and b values are found by finding where the derivative of E and the second derivative of E are equal to 0

Comment: I get it now!! Thanks.